# Exception when perform a segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I use Swift2 and Xcode 7.1

I want to trigger a segue when I click on a collectionCell that is present in a tableViewCell.
Only I have a identifier error.

Yet I have said my good segue into my storyboard.

[image]
[image]
Error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'look''

[image]

```
    class PostsCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var controller: PostsController!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        controller.perform(data![indexPath.item])

    }

    // ...

}
```

My Controller :

```
class PostsController: UITableViewController {

// ....

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...
}

// ...

func perform(post: Post) {
    self.post = post
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("look", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "look") {
        let viewController:SeePostController = segue.destinationViewController as! SeePostController
        viewController.data = self.post
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Yes i have the same problem ...

Comment: I can not let my line with "self.performWithIdentifier()". Else, my code doesn't compile ...

Comment: You have the error in PostCell right? Remove self.performSegueWithIdentifier("look", sender: self)  from there and keep it in PostsController.

Comment: In this case I have an identifier error

Comment: Thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<project.PostsController:>) has no segue with identifier 'look''

Comment: And now it´s crashing at self.performSegueWithIdentifier("look", sender: self)? Try to add a button and drag a action Outlet in PostsController and add self.performSegueWithIdentifier("look", sender: self) and see if that works.

Comment: Yes it work with the button !

Comment: Yes it is exactly that! It can not find the segue ...

Comment: I can not because my collectionView is in a TableViewCell my TableViewController

Comment: Can you add the segue to your PostsCell (in your storyboard) and then also move your prepareForSegue function to PostsCell?

Comment: I succeeded !!!  I added a variable that contains my control instance to trigger perform on this instance.

Comment: The answer you would like to write for me to valid? You earn points! ;)

Comment: Great, glad it worked out for you. Good luck :)

Comment: What variable did you add?

Comment: I have update my PostCell

Comment: Great, I have updated my answer so that others can make us of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `PostsController().performSegueWithIdentifier("look", sender: self)` use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("look", sender: self)`

**Update**
Create a new instance of your viewcontroller and call your perform method.

```
var controller: PostsController!
controller.perform(data![indexPath.item])
```

Comment: I can't because I'm in a UITableViewCell

Comment: Yes you can, try it @HugoFouquet

Comment: I have 'Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegueWithIdentifier''

Comment: You´re using Swift right? Try to Clean your project and restart Xcode. You do call performSegueWithIdentifier with self.

Comment: Could you add more code in your question so that I can try to help you solve this.